# Lockout of console! Help required!

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, aaa, authorization

I'm locked out of the console after applying two AAA authorization statements

```
aaa new-model
aaa authorization console
aaa authorization exec default group tacacs+ none
```

Now my customer requires me to remedy the lockout without rebooting the switch

Hardware is Switch Cisco 4507 IOS 15.2

Can anyone advise on this ?

---

```
Switch con0 is now available
Press RETURN to get started.
% Authorization failed.
```

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cisco maintains a page with links to the password recovery procedures for a lot of devices:

[*Password Recovery Procedures*](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ios-nx-os-software/ios-software-releases-121-mainline/6130-index.html)

You will need to restart the switch to get to ROMMON in order to recover the password and fix the configuration, unless you can get in on a VTY or AUX line.

Comment: Hi Ron , Thank you for sharing. However the customer will not allow the Switch to reboot. Password recovery procedures require rebooting the Switch.

Comment: You must reload the switch in order to do what you want to do. There is no other way. This is something that you must do after hours or at a time when you can reload the switch. You must get into ROMMON to be able to load the configuration with no password in order to fix the configuration, unless you can get in on a VTY or AUX line.

Comment: Hi Ron, 
There are no layer 3 access . Vty access is not available , aux access is not inside the line configs also.

Comment: Then you must reload the switch. Sorry, but that is how it is. It is part of the security, and it is not supposed to be easy or hackable. It requires physical access to and a reload of the switch.

Comment: Hi Ron , Thank you for sharing! Will check with Cisco TAC on the alternatives.

Comment: If you get an answer, then post it here and accept it, or accept my answer. If you do not accept an answer, the question will keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.

Comment: Cisco TAC will say the same as Ron.

Comment: Hi Ron my Switch Hardware is Cisco 4507 , it has 2 ports on the Sup Card WS-X45-SUP8L-E , 1 console port and 1 management port. I will try to console the management port to see if i have success before i accept your answer. Thank you!

Comment: The management interface is an ethernet interface, and you must have configured an IP address on it. It does not work like a console interface.

Comment: Hi Ron i am also exploring reverse telnet to the Cisco 4507 .  reboot is costly to the customer and not an option in this case. I am given till end of today to let the customer know the status

Comment: That will give you the same result as the console connection because you are going through the console. It is simply using another router to connect through the console so that you can do it remotely, but it is still just a console connection. The customer is just going to need to realize that the switch needs to be reloaded to regain administrative access.

Comment: Thanks Ron, I have stopped pursuing alternatives. You are right. Thanks for the advices.